# How to loop through previous sibling's elements instead of next sibling's elements using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Based on the following HTML structure below, jquery's each function would loop through the following jquery code starting at id "startHere" down to the next sibling with class name of below

```
            $("#startHere").each(function(index, value)
            {
                alert$(this).text(index));
            });

           <tr><td class='above'><td></tr>
           <tr><td class='above'><td></tr>
           <tr><td class='above'><td></tr>
           <tr id='startHere'><td><td></tr>
           <tr><td class='below'><td></tr>
           <tr><td class='below'><td></tr>
           <tr><td class='below'><td></tr>
           <tr><td class='below'><td></tr>
```

How do I get the each function to loop through the previous siblings with class name of "above" starting at id "startHere"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```js
var log = (function () {
    var $log = $('#log');
    return function (msg) {
        $('<p/>', {text: msg}).appendTo($log)
    }
})();

//set some content for the td
$('table td').text(function(i){return i;})


$("#startHere").prevAll().find('.above').each(function (index, value) {
    log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td class='above'></td></tr>
  <tr><td class='above'></td></tr>
  <tr><td class='above'></td></tr>
  <tr id='startHere'><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td class='below'></td></tr>
  <tr><td class='below'></td></tr>
  <tr><td class='below'></td></tr>
  <tr><td class='below'></td></tr>
</table>

<div id="log"></div>
```

- [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll) - Find all the previous tr elements
- [.find('.above')](http://api.jquery.com/find) - Find the `td.above` elements

Comment: @MangeshParte yes... just fixed that